# ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'mytable'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, innodb

After upgrading mysql from 5.5 to 5.7, a compressed innodb database seems corrupted. I followed the method in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047721/mysql-innodb-error-1034-incorrect-key-file-for-table-tablename-try-to-repair) to create a new database/table, drop the tablespace, copy the old .ibd file, then import the tablespace with `ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE` but got the same error as in that post:

```
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'mytable'; try to repair it
```

Note that this error is not caused by insufficient disk space.

Comment: Please provide your rationale for using "compressed".  I may attempt to convince you to abandon that little-used feature of InnoDB.

Comment: @RickJames I compress the database to save disk space because it is too large(over 10GB) and increasing every day.

Comment: You have a disk that won't hold 10GB?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I would like to see what column(s) could benefit from compression.  And I may have other tips (such as avoiding `BIGINT`).

Comment: @RickJames, CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `title` varchar(700) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `ctime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

Answer (score 1):

```
PRIMARY KEY (title(255))
```

Ouch!  Technically that says that the first 255 characters of `title` are unique.  This is probably not what you wanted.  I think that prefixing UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY should be disallowed.

I *guess* that the prefixing is what is causing the problem.

5.7 will let you remove the `(255)` and (presumably) work correctly.  Try that.  (5.5 had index limitations that led to the prefixing.)

Comment: I drop the primary key and import the tablespace again. Unfortunately, the error persists.

Comment: Interestingly, when importing tablespace, mysql log shows this error: [ERROR] InnoDB: Page offset doesn't match file offset: page offset: 526288, file offset: 526288
[Note] InnoDB: Discarding tablespace of table `mydatabase`.`mytable`: Data structure corruption,   but page offset=file offset obviously.